# Paralelization python list comprehension not enhancing performance

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Recently I have been trying to parallelize some list comprehensions to speed up my code but I found out that the parallelization lead to a worse time execution... can someone help me understand why?

my computer is an i7 4 cores 8 threads around 3GHz core speed and I am using python 2.7

Here you have an example of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mulpro
import itertools
d1 = 0.1;
d2 = 0.2;
data = range(100000) #Array of data
#example of list comprehension
data2 = [i + np.random.uniform(d1,d2) for i in data] #this is faster than the following
#example of multiprocessing
def parAddRandom(array):
    array = list(array)
    return (array[0] + np.random.uniform(array[1],array[2]))
pool = mulpro.Pool(processes=8)
data3 =  pool.map(parAddRandom, itertools.izip(data, itertools.repeat(d1), itertools.repeat(d2)))
```

I would expect the code to be faster by parallelization, as 8 cores are being used except from just 1, but it is not...

EDIT:

If I modify the code so the function parAddRandom only accepts one value then it is extremely faster...

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mulpro
import itertools
data = range(100000) #Array of data
#example of list comprehension
data2 = [i + np.random.uniform(d1,d2) for i in data] #Now this is not faster than the following
#example of multiprocessing
def parAddRandom(value):
    return (value + np.random.uniform(0.1,0.2))
pool = mulpro.Pool(processes=8)
data3 =  pool.map(parAddRandom, data)
```

But I still need to be able to modify the parameters "d1" and "d2" from the previous code...

Comment: To my knowledge, the OS is already uses all cores to fasten that prosedure, which means a parallelization in the background. So it already uses the cpu in full extent. When you create threads, you just divide cpu power which results in more operations to solve the same problem with same resources.

Comment: To my knowlegde, in python 2.7 list comprehension only uses one core and one thread... http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/313013/is-python-list-comprehension-using-multi-threading-or-parallelized-in-any-way-by

Comment: Then forgive me, the other thing that comes to my mind is that GIL may be slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Because your function is small the overhead of the function call (and other multiprocessing machinery) is dominant )

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

d1 = 0.1;
d2 = 0.2;

def parAddRandom(array):

    return (array[0] + np.random.uniform(array[1],array[2]))


array = 45436, d1, d2
with_function_calling = timeit.timeit("parAddRandom(array)", globals=globals())

without_function_calling = timeit.timeit("array[0] + np.random.uniform(array[1],array[2])", globals=globals())

print ("function call adds {:0.2f}% overhead :(".format((100.0*with_function_calling/without_function_calling) - 100.0))
```

> function *alone* call adds 18.59% overhead :(

My guess is that the other multiprocessing machinery add almost 100% in your example ...

If you want this to be effective you'll have to create a function that takes a bigger chunk each time.